# How can I get my Android layout with fragments to display properly based on data sent from one fragment to another?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am working on an app, in which I am using tabs/fragments. I based my app on an example I found on the internet [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/).

What I have is a ListView in Home tab that displays a list of classes. What I want to happen is when I click on a class in the list, it will send an ID to the Class tab, where I want to populate another ListView of students within that class based on the passed-in class ID. I am having issues getting this to work properly.

Currently, it mostly works.

This is what I have for the layout in Class tab (i.e., the receiving tab):

**class.xml**

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/class_information_layout">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/class_id_display" />
    <LinearLayout>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/column1_row_header" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/column2_row_header" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/column3_row_header" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/column4_row_header" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/column5_row_header" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+swipe_container" />
        <ListView android:id="@+student_row"></ListView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the class that is populating that layout:

**ClassInformation.java**

```
package myPackage;

public class ClassInformation extends Fragment {

    private View rootView;
    private ListView myListView;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout mySwipeRefresh;
    private DatabaseHelper myDBHelper;
    private Cursor informationCursor;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter mySimpleCursorAdapter;
    private static String classID = "select a class first";

    private TextView classIDDisplay;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.class, container, false);
        classIDDisplay = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.class_id_display);
        myListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.student_row);
        mySwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View rootView, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onViewCreated(rootView, savedInstanceState);

        if(getArguments() != null){
            classID = getArguments().getString("classID");
        }
        System.out.println("Class ID: " + classID);

        drawTheView();

        mySwipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener(){
            @Override
            public void onRefresh(){
                mySwipeRefrehs.setRefreshing(false);
                drawTheView();
            }
        });
    }

    private void drawTheView(){

        myDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());

        informationCursor = myDBHelper.getInformationCursor(classID);
        String[] fromColumns = {"studentID", "firstname", "lastname", "homephone", "homeaddress"};
        int[] toViews = {R.id.studentID_textview, R.id.firstname_textview, R.id.lastname_textview, R.id.homephone_textview, R.id.homeaddress_textview};
        mySimpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.student_information, informationCursor, fromColumns, toViews, 0);

        classIDDisplay.setText("Class ID: " + classID);

        myListView.setAdapter(mySimpleCursorAdapter);

        myDBHelper.close();
    }
}
```

This is the student_information layout that get populated with the adapter:

**student_information.xml**

```
<LinearLayout>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/column1_data" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/column2_data" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/column3_data" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/column4_data" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/column5_data" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the Home tab class that sends the information to the Class tab for display:

**Home.java**

```
package myPackage;

public class Home extends Fragment {

    private View rootView;
    private DatabaseHelper myDBHelper;
    private Cursor classCursor;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter mySimpleCursorAdapter;
    private Activity myActivity;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);

        ViewPager myViewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity.findViewById(R.id.pager);

        myDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());

        classCursor = myDBHelper.getClassCursor();
        String[] fromColumns = {"classID"};
        int[] toViews = {R.id.class_id_textview};
        mySimpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.class_layout, classCursor, fromColumns, toViews, 0);

        ListView myListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.class_row);

        myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Cursor subCursor = (Cursor) mySimpleCursorAdapter.getItem(position);
                String classID = subCursor.getString(subCursor.getColumnIndex("classID"));

                ClassInformation classInformation = new ClassInformation();
                Bundle myBundle = new Bundle();
                myBundle.putString("classID", classID);
                classInformation.setArguments(myBundle);
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.class_information_layout, classInformation).commit();
                myViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
            }
        });

        myListView.setAdapter(mySimpleCursorAdapter);

        myDBHelper.close();

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Currently, when I first start the app, and click a class in the Home tab, the Class tab does not get the "id" from the Home tab, so the list of students does not populate. However, and this is the weird part, if I (1) click off of my Class tab to another tab that is not the Home tab and go back to the Class tab, or (2) swipe down using the SwipeRefreshLayout, the list of students will be drawn correctly.

Then, if I go back to the Home tab and select a different class, my class tab still shows the first class I chose. And again, if I (1) click off of my Class tab to another tab that is not the Home tab and go back to the Class tab, or (2) swipe down using the SwipeRefreshLayout, the list of students will be drawn correctly with the new class' data.

I am not getting any errors, it just will not display correctly until I click off the tab or swipe refresh.

I have a System.out.println in the ClassInformation.java file. This is the result of clicking around my app:

```
Start the app
    System.out.println = "select a class first"
Click on a class in the Home tab
    - System.out.println = "Class ID = <number>"
    - nothing in the list
Click off of the Class tab, then back to the class tab -or- use the swipe refresh
    - System.out.println = "Class ID = <number>"
    - the list is populated correctly
Click a different class in the Home tab
    - System.out.println = "<first class ID>"
    - the list is not populated correctly
Click off of the Class tab, then back to the class tab -or- use the swipe refresh
    - System.out.println = "Class ID = <new class number>"
    - the list is populated correctly
```

**-or-**

```
Start the app
    - System.out.println = "select a class first"
Click on a class in the Home tab
    - System.out.println = "Class ID = <number>"
    - nothing in the list
Swipe Refresh
    - System.out.println = "Class ID = <number>"
    - the list is populated correctly
Click a different class in the Home tab
    - System.out.println = "<first class ID>"
    - the list is not populated correctly
Swipe Refresh
    - System.out.println = "Class ID = <new class number>"
    - the list is populated correctly
```

I feel this should be a simple fix, but I seem to keep overlooking the answer.

Comment: In the Home fragment why are you doing another transaction, when the Class fragment is already present? You can access the Home fragment with ClassInformation f = (ClassInformation) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(
                       "android:switcher:"+R.id.pager+":1"); f.setClassId(); . In the code above replace 1 with the actual position of the ClassInformation in the ViewPager. The method setClassId()(in ClassInformation) would look like this public void setClassId(String id) { classID = id; if (getView() != null) {drawTheView();}}.

Comment: When I try this, I get a Null Pointer Exception because my "ClassInformation f" is null. Although I do get a String back when I use findFragmentByTag.

Comment: What type of adapter do you use with your ViewPager? Did you use the right position according to the position of ClasInformation in the ViewPager(the position start from 0)?

Comment: My adapter (PagerAdapter) extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter. Yes, I used the correct position.

Comment: What I said above was for the case when you use a FragmentPagerDapter.  Do you have a lot of fragments or is there any reason you used the FragmentStatePagerAdapter? Can you use the FragmentPagerAdapter instead to test out?

Comment: I have about 10 fragments, I don't know if that is a lot. No, I have no reason to use FragmentStatePagerAdapter, it was the one used in the example I found. Also, I am having to use "getFragmentManager" as opposed to "getSupportFragmentManager", as the latter is not available to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103648/discussion-between-luksprog-and-brian).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want to happen is when I click on a class in the list, it will
>   send an ID to the Class tab, where I want to populate another ListView
>   of students within that class based on the passed-in class ID

At the moment you're doing a transaction to add a new ClassInformation fragment but you already have the fragment in the ViewPager so instead you could(and should) access it and  set the new id(along with refreshing the view). If you use a FragmentPagerAdapter with your ViewPager you could access that fragment by using a special tag(specific to FragmentPagerAdapter) like this:

```
ClassInformation f = (ClassInformation) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:"+R.id.pager+":" + the_position_of_classinformation_in_viewpager); 
f.setClassId(classID);
```

The method setClassId() could look like this:

```
public void setClassId(String id) {
    classID = id; 
    if (getView() != null) {// just in case we call it when the view is not built yet
        drawTheView();
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer worked perfectly ... THANKS!

I'll award the bounty in 22 hours, as soon as StackOverflow unlocks this ability.